# how to declare a std::list of the base class in static polymophism?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

quick question, when i have some static polymophism classes

```
template <class Derived>
struct base
{
}

struct derived1 : public base<derived1>{
}

//do the same for derived2, derived3.
```

how to declare a std::list that will contains a lot of derived1 derive2 derived3 objects? something like std::list < base > ? i guess not, right?

PS: Apparently the derived classes would be selected at run-time, and i need to access the functionality of the derived classes at run-time.

THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use CRTP, you’ll need to define a common base class for all the instantiations of your `base` class template:

```
class base_base { public: virtual ~base_base() = default; };
template<typename T> class base : public base_base;
```

Second, you need extra indirection, so you’ll have to use `std::unique_ptr`.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

std::list<std::unique_ptr<base>> my_list;
my_list.emplace_back(make_unique<derived1>());
my_list.emplace_back(make_unique<derived2>());
my_list.emplace_back(make_unique<derived3>());
```

In C++14 you’ll most likely be able to use `std::make_unique`, so you won’t have to define that function yourself.

Comment: Merci. could explain a bit why we must use unique_ptr here? why i cannot simply use a boost::shared_ptr? thanks!

Comment: @ccfenix `boost::shared_ptr` should work fine, but it’s highly unlikely you need shared ownership.

Comment: @Elyse I'm also curious why you want a make_unique and also why you define a virtual method for static polymorphism..?

Comment: @TomSmartBishop `new` is too error prone. Consider `f(unique_ptr<T>(new T), unique_ptr<T>(new T))`. If either `new` throws, you're screwed, due to implementation-definedness of order of evaluation.

Comment: Virtual method? Not sure. Was long ago.

Comment: @rightfold: Thanks and now totally agree on make_unique ;)